# Syntax coloring input using Sweave with TeXShop?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I've just started using Sweave on TeXShop ( which runs on OSX). Is it possible to have syntax coloring of the source code so that I can distinguish between raw text and R-code?

For example, the following code snippet in my Sweave file is the same as the rest of the text, which makes it harder to read than an R editor that has syntax coloring.

```
<<reg, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
a = c(10,15)
plot(a, a)
@
```

(I have also tried this out using the wonderful [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) which does have syntax coloring for both R and Latex, but I think TexShop is superior for LaTeX.)

Comment: You should take a look at `highlight` package. It can produce LaTeX output.

Comment: My mistake, you need `pgfSweave` - take a look at my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe TexShop supports mode switching (e.g. highlighting in two different languages--R and LaTeX--within the same file), since it was designed around a single language (LaTeX).  Editors that do and therefore properly handle Sweave are to my knowledge:

- Eclipse with Stat/ET
- RStudio
- Emacs with ESS

Comment: TextMate also does this too but I love the TexShop engine system so I live with the lack of coloring in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use highlighted syntax out of the box. Use `pgfSweave` package. Just add `pgf=TRUE` (and `echo=TRUE`) to your Sweave chunk, and you're good to go. Install `pgfSweave`, and load a package vignette (`vignette("pgfSweave")`) for further assistance.

> Version 1.1.0 of pgfSweave introduced
>   the highlight option. The default is
>   TRUE by default so code will be
>   syntax-highlighted with the highlight
>   package.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the syntax coloring within my raw source code; not the compiled code. If I understand your answer I think you are referring to syntax coloring for the output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't read your question thoroughly. No wonder noone replied so far. Well... I have no experience with MacOS, but Emacs with ESS has LaTeX/R syntax colouring, if that's fine for you. =/ Sorry once again for my mistake(s).

Comment: No problem; thanks for answering anyway. I added an extra 'input' to the title to make it a bit clearer.